# Missings values in csv file datasets for machine learning

Tags: csv, machine-learning

I have a csv file which contains missing values.How can i handle the missing?One thing is that I can replace this values with very large negative value like -99999.Will it be a good technique?Here is the csv file:

```
length,weight,height,price
2,9,,8
7,,2,7
1,,,2
,,2,3
```

Note: The real csv file is very large containing many columns and rows.

Comment: it totally depends on what kind of data you have.  In general, I have never seen someone replacing  Null values by large neg number

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar You see sentdex tuitorial implementing KNN algorithm

Comment: Read about [Imputing the missing values](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#imputation-of-missing-values).

Comment: agree with @VivekKumar, I would prefer it over zhilevan answer.

Comment: @VivekKumar I am getting this error after transforming X:ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 5938
1]

Comment: @VivekKumar i think the error was due to the fact that X & y shape was unequal so I transformed y also.But now I am getting this error:    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (2, 2)

Comment: How did you transform it? Using Imputer? Then please add the code and some samples which are giving this error. Maybe upload the csv and link here.

Comment: @VivekKumar Can you please give details on the parametrs of fit() & X??

Comment: @mushahid have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Handling of missing values is a full topic in machine learning and data analysis.

If you are just trying to put a specific value for missing variable, it's better to replace with a value that cannot be taken by the variable. How can you guarantee that your variable cannot take -99999 value and what will happen if you want to find the minimum of this variable after missing value imputation.

Personaly, I would let missing values as displayed in your example, with just nothing. I you really want to put a value, I think it would be better to put "NULL", "MISSING" or any string, if your variable are numerics.

Then, to impute, you can do the following, depending on the missing values pattern (amount and distributions of missing values, corellation of missing values with variables, ...):

- Drop all rows with missing values.
- Impute missing values with a value like row mean or row median (for continuous variables) (not recommanded)
- Impute missing value with advanced techics (Multiple Imputation by Chained Equation or MICE for example)
- Treat missing value as a specific category (for categorical variables)

Comment: I tried replacing the missing value with mean,but getting the accuracy very low using SVM with rbf kernel.

Comment: Mean imputation is usualy not recommanded, because it affect the distribution of the variables. Nonetheless, it should not have a strong effect on your accuracy, except if you have a really high percentage of missing value. Given your comment, I would say that low accuray is mostly due to others causes, like not enough variable, not enough observations...

Comment: With median I also tried but getting the same accuracy.Yes,I have a lot of missing value.What approach should I try?The datasets size is around 50000*150.

Comment: If you really want to impute, I would recommand MICE method, but keep in mind that it introduce lot of bias in your data.

Comment: My missing data contains both categorical and continuous variables.Can you please give some details on MICE method?

Comment: Please give some details on how to implement MICE method??

Comment: Also I am getting an import error in  fancyimpute library.Please help..

Answer (score -2):

This a technique in Data engineering called transformation ( and one part of is data cleansing), you have to use some libraries to transform data and handle missed data. I strongly suggest

[Optimus](https://hioptimus.com/)

> Optimus is the missing framework for cleansing (cleaning and much
>   more), pre-processing and exploratory data analysis in a distributed
>   fashion with Apache Spark
>
> Optimus is the missing framework for cleaning and pre-processing data in a distributed fashion. It uses all the power of Apache Spark
>   (optimized via Catalyst) to do so. It implements several handy tools
>   for data wrangling and munging that will make your life much easier.
>   The first obvious advantage over any other public data cleaning
>   library or framework is that it will work on your laptop or your big
>   cluster, and second, it is amazingly easy to install, use and
>   understand.

There are a lot of examples you can simply extend them to your job.

as example you can easily find NaN field and replace them with -99999

```
    # Import optimus
    import optimus as op
    # Instance of Utilities class
    tools = op.Utilities()
    # Reading df from web
    path = "yourcsv.csv"
    df = tools.read_url(path=path)
  # Instantiation of DataTransformer class:
    transformer = op.DataFrameTransformer(df)
    # Replace NA with -99999's
    transformer.replace_na(-99999, columns="*")
    # Show DF
    transformer.show()
```